# What's the importance of proving that $0,1$ are unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I had a course in the construction of numbers last semester. I understand the potencial of most of the proofs, for example: I guess I can answer decently why commutativity is important.

But when it comes to the proof of uniqueness of $0,1$, I have no idea why that is important. For $\Bbb{N}$, I guess it's important because using peano axioms, we could have:

$$0\to 1 \to 2 \to \dots$$

$$0'\to 1' \to 2' \to \dots$$

Inside $\Bbb{N}$, but I'm not sure if that is the reason, nor what problem it would represent.

Comment: Did you have any group theory in that course? If not, it becomes important because the uniqueness of those elements become generalized in group theory as the uniqueness of the identity element (which 1 and 0 are examples of). So, it can be used in structures in which that is not obvious. Also, it can be used to prove other results.

Comment: If it weren't the case that the identity elements were unique, this would open up a whole new area of math - the study of rings or fields that have more than one (additive and/or multiplicative) identity.  So its good to rule out the existence of such things before one gets started.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to think about the order, and ask about arithmetic.

What would $1'+0$ be? What would $3+0'$ be? If you have two chains, you need to handle "cross chain addition" or multiplication. Of course that is doable, but then adding two additive neutral element would be $0=0+0'=0'$. So the chain is unique.

More generally the uniqueness of $0$ and $1$ allow us to omit them from the language, since they are definable. And it allows us to add them back when needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to make sure we aren't working in the [trivial ring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrivialRing.html). Ideally the axioms we assume for $\mathbb{N}$ should eliminate the possibility that $\mathbb{N}$ is the trivial ring; a proof that $0 \neq 1$ is one way to do that.